# $T_1$space on cocountable topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ is uncountable set with cocountable topology. is $(X,T)$ a $T_1$space?

I tried to solve it in following way but I don't know it is correct or no? Is it sufficient?

I know this topology is $T_1$-space if for every element $x$ in $X$, $\{x\}$ is closed. Given $x\neq y$ , if $\{y\}$ is open set containing $x$ but not $y$. So $X$ is $T_1$-space.

Comment: I don’t think that you said what you intended to say: $\{y\}$ isn’t an open set containing $x$ but not $y$. If you meant $X\setminus\{y\}$, then yes, that shows that $X$ is $T_1$.

Comment: Yes I mean $X\backslash\|{y|}$. and there is not necessary to show $\{x\}$ or $\{y\}$ is closed?

Comment: You essentially have shown that: if $x\in X$, let $U_x=X\setminus\{x\}$. Then $X\setminus U_x=\{x\}$ is countable, so $U_x$ is open, and therefore $\{x\}=X\setminus U_x$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

> **Lemma**: Given a topological space $X$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ is a $T_1$ space (singletons are closed).
> 2. All finite subsets of $X$ are closed.
> 3. All cofinite subsets of $X$ are open.

That 1 and 2 are equivalent is readily seen, since every finite set is a finite union of singletons, and finite unions of closed sets are closed. That 2 and 3 are equivalent follows from the definition of cofinite, and the fact that a set is closed if and only if its complement is open.

Since every finite set is countable, then every cofinite set is cocountable, whence the cocountable topology on an uncountable set is a $T_1$ topology. Actually, this is true for the cocountable topology on *any* set, though if the underlying set is countable, then the cocountable topology will be the discrete topology.